# MySQL high CPU usage with InnoDB

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, cpu

I'm getting very high MySQL CPU utilization on my VPS server (about 80% CPU usage constantly, even without any queries.)

If I disable InnoDB, using the following lines in my.cnf,

```
ignore-builtin-innodb
default-storage-engine = myisam
```

I get 0% CPU utilization, which leads me to think that there is some problem with the InnoDB implementation that causes high CPU usage.

Is there any way to debug this? (Showing the process list in mysql doesn't give me any relevant information at all.)

MySQL version: 5.5.29

(I'm also using nginx)

Answer (score 0):

The problem may stem from the fact that InnoDB's default settings are still of a single-threaded nature. Now that you are using MySQL 5.5, you can configure InnoDB to access multiple CPUs/cores.

Rather than reinvent the wheel, please read my posts from the DBA StackExchange:

- `Sep 20, 2011` : [Multi cores and MySQL Performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/5968/877)
- `Sep 12, 2011` : [Possible to make MySQL use more then one core](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/5670/877)
- `May 26, 2011` : [About single threaded versus multithreaded databases performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/2948/877)

Please read through, and I hope it helps.